# Array In Post Data Afnetworking Gives Error - Required Data Missing

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Hii I am using afnetworking from post array data to sent server side here is my code ...

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dict1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"online_status",@"option_name",dict[@"option_value"],@"option_value", nil];
    NSArray *arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:dict1, nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict2=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[UserDefaults valueForKey:@"user_id"],@"user_id",arr1,@"option_array", nil];



    NSError *error = nil;
            NSString *createJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict2
                                                                                                  options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                                                                    error:&error]
                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSDictionary *pardsams = @{@"data": createJSON};

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSLog(@"Dict %@",pardsams[@"data"]);

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@set_user_multiple_options",K_APP_URL] parameters:        pardsams[@"data"] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];
```

and getting server responce is :

```
message = "Required parameters missing.";
status = 0;
```

i will hit the request to rest client but where getting correct responce saved data bt trying to do in code it not working polease... help me

Comment: To sort out this kind of issue, you ideally need to be able to capture the http packets as they pass through the network. That way you can compare what your code is sending against what your REST client is sending. Run Wireshark on your client machine. https://www.wireshark.org

Comment: Are you sure your post parameters should be pardsams[@"data"] ? Try posting pardsams instead, ie, post the entire dictionary.

Comment: Set the manager.requestSerializer to the AFJSON one. Then, in `params:` parameter, just put the NSDictionary (not JSONSerialized), which should be either `dict2`, or `@{@"data",dict2}`.